# AngularJS: Getting siblings of routed item

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Ok so I'm using routing to drill down into a specific item based on it's ID (but also capturing it's category)

```
$http.get('http://something.co.uk/?category='+$routeParams.storyCat+'&id='+$routeParams.storyID)
```

This gives a URL of http://website.co.uk/index.html#/category/103 with the story details coming from the data on the server based on the ID of the item you clicked.

The following functions are then run on swipe (using angular-touch) which increase or decrease the ID by one, showing the next or previous story.

```
$scope.nextStory = function () {
    var storyID = Number($routeParams.storyID);
    var storyCat = $routeParams.storyCat;
    var path = '/' + storyCat + '/' + (storyID + 1 );
    $location.path(path);
};
$scope.previousStory = function () {
    var storyID = Number($routeParams.storyID);
    var storyCat = $routeParams.storyCat;
    var path = '/' + storyCat + '/' + (storyID - 1 );
    $location.path(path);
};
```

The problem with this is that it literally just goes up and down the ID's. I need it to only go through ID's which match the Category of the item you are on.

For example if you click into story ID 95, which is in a category called "Bags" and then you swipe left, I need it to not simply show story 96 which might be in a different category, but instead find the next story within "Bags" and show that one.

Can this even be done using AngularJS and routing or do I need a completely different approach?

Comment: You'll need to provide us with how these categories/stories are created/stored. The only way angular will know where to go will be if they're in the javascript somehow.

Comment: There is a load of JSON data stored on a server. This lists all the stories with ID's and categories amongst other things and the relevant items are extracted using parameters in the URLs

Comment: Then you'll have to involve the server somehow in knowing what the next/previous story is.